# ¿Cómo hacer un gráfico de barras apilado donde mis valores negativos se acumulen hacia abajo y los positivos hacia arriba en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Este es el código en R del ejemplo que explico.
Como pueden notar existen valores egativos en mi matriz, pero al momento de aplicar barras apiladas algunos valores desaparecen pues las barras apiladas se acumulan y si son valores negativos va hacia abajo pero cuando viene un valor positivo va hacia arriba eliminando o sobreescribiendo ese valor. Se puede observar esto con los colores que di a cada columna.
lo que quiero es que todos los valores negativos vayan abajo y los positivos vayan hacia arriba independientemente. No que se sumen o resten entre ellos. En pocas que los 5 colores esten siempre en cada gráfico de barras apilado sea positivo o negativo.

```
x=c(-1,2,3,4,5)
y=c(5,4,6,-8,10)
z=c(3,-3,4.5,6,-7.5)
tabla=cbind(x,y,z)
b=barplot(tabla,
        main = "Gráfico de barras apilado",
        xlab = "Tipo de transmisión", ylab = "Frecuencia", ylim = c(-10,20),
        col = c("darkgrey", "darkblue", "red", "pink","green"),
        legend.text = rownames(tabla),
        beside = FALSE) # Barras apiladas (opción por defecto)
```

Y así sería la imagen con el problema que tengo:

[image: Como pueden observar no estan todos mis valores independientes ya que se suman o restan - con los clores se puede ver de mejor manera - lo que deseo es que todos mis valores esten junto con sus colorcitos]

Answer (score 1):

Lo haría con `ggplot2`.

De la siguiente manera.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

tabla %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(t=1:n()) %>% gather(key="Eje_x",value = "valor",1:3) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Eje_x, y=valor, fill=factor(t)))+
  geom_col(show.legend = F)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se ha hecho es crear una variable que identifique a cada una de las categorías de las filas. Luego se lleva a formato largo para que se conserve cada uno como si fuese independiente. Esto se especifica en gráfico como `fill=factor(t)`.

Entendí que deseabas algo así. Si es así, ahí lo tienes.

¿Se puede hacer en R base?
Sí.
Tendré que echarle una pensada para poder hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Me imagino que debe haber algún parámetro que te permite modificar el tipo de barras

Te adjunto una solución en **plotly** para complementar:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
```

Le damos formato a los datos:

```
tabla = data.frame(tabla) %>%
  mutate(grupo = 1:nrow(tabla)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = !grupo,
               names_to = "ejes",
               values_to = "valores") %>%
  mutate(ejes = as.factor(ejes))
```

Generamos el grafico:

```
plot_ly(
  data = tabla,
  x = ~ ejes,
  y = ~ valores,
  type = "bar",
  color = ~ factor(grupo),
  colors = c("darkgrey", "darkblue", "red", "pink", "green")
) %>%
  layout(
    barmode = 'relative', # A esto me refiero con lo de especificar
    title = list(text = "Gráfico de barras apilado"),
    xaxis = list(title = "Tipo de transmisión"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Frecuencia")
  )
```

En plotly barmode = 'relative', es la parte donde se especifica que los valores se representen de la manera que necesitamos

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]